# Spring webflux request callback not working

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using spring-webflux 5.1.7-RELEASE. I want to trigger the callback for webclient just before the request is sent. The code for this is:

```
ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest (SomeLogObject someLogObject) {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
        /**
         business logic for callback goes here
         */
        return Mono.just(clientRequest);
    });
}

//code for plugging in logRequest callback (at some othe place)
WebClient webClient = WebClient
        .builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
        .baseUrl(baseURL)
        .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest(someLogObject)))
        .build();

webClient
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("some_uri_path").queryParams(queryParam).build())
        .header("some_header_key", "some_header_value")
        .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Here the logRequest is triggered in beginning itself (much before the request is triggered). As per my debugging I found that it gets triggered when retrieve() is called.

Is there a way to ensure that logRequest gets triggered immediately before the request is sent and NOT when the mono is created?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a full [mcve]? I'd expect `logRequest()` to get called immediately, but I'd expect the "business logic for callback" you've marked to be executed just as the request is made, not when the mono is created.

Comment: @MichaelBerry you are right logRequest() is called immediately . however business logic is also called in the call to retrieve() method. i want to delay it till just before the request execution. business logic is a log statement. It logs the timestamp when the request started executing e.g. log.info("start time is ",currtimeinmillis)

Comment: i dont really understand what it is you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following change:

```
ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest (SomeLogObject someLogObject){
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest ->
            Mono.defer(() -> {
                /**
                 business logic for callback goes here
                 */
                return Mono.just(clientRequest);
            })
    );
}
```

`Mono.defer()` will delay code execution until the real request.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you

Comment: I tried this. defer works for my case. I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear that!